# Draytek Vigor 2820 static IP's

Tags: networking, router, static-ip, wide-area-network, draytek

I have a Draytek Vigor 2820 router which is connected to our ADSL provider (British Telecom, BT).

We currently have one static IP address which is accessible from anywhere outside of our network and points at a simple web server on port 80.

We have just been given 5 more static IP addresses which I would like to point at five servers that have static IP's.

As an example:

```
Current static IP -      80.123.123.123
New Static IP's   -      100.100.100.100-105


Server IP's       -      192.168.1.129-133
```

I have confused myself completely between NAT addresses, static routes and WAN IP aliases. If anyone can give me a clear idea of what I need to do it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the Multi-NAT functionality identified for your Draytek Vigor 2820 should support the multiple WAN IP address assignments. Typically one WAN IP is identified as the main IP used for all outbound traffic. That IP as well as the other WAN IP addresses can then be identified in various port mapping assignments for inbound traffic to internal servers/services - much like what you already have in place for port 80, but just additional mappings referring to the respective WAN to LAN configurations.

Comment: I've added the new static IP addresses as WAN IP Aliases and I've added a port redirection for the first of the new ip addresses which has pointed the new public IP to the internal IP address (port 80) but it hasn't had any effect.

Comment: Have you checked the logs of the new forwarded web server? If so, what/any entries?